Minkowski type inequalities for different exponents
In order to show the uniform boundedness of a particular operator, I have to use inequalities like: $d^{\alpha}-c^{\alpha} \leq (d-c)^{\alpha}$  and $(d-c)^{\alpha} \leq d^{\alpha}-c^{\alpha}$ for $0<c<d$ and $d-c>1$.
I know that $d^{\alpha}-c^{\alpha} \leq (d-c)^{\alpha}$ for $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $(d-c)^{\alpha} \leq d^{\alpha} - c^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\geq 1.$
I'm wondering if there exists some constant $K$ that doesn't depend neither on $d$ nor on $c$ such that $d^{\alpha}-c^{\alpha} \leq K(d-c)^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\geq 1.$
In the context $d-c$ represent the measure of the interval $[c,d]$ which contains the support of a class of functions.

Assume $\alpha > 1$. Look at the expression $$\phi(t) = \frac{t^\alpha - 1}{(t-1)^\alpha}$$ for $t > 1$. According to L'Hospital's rule you get
$$\lim_{t \to 1^+} \phi(t) = \lim_{t \to 1^+} \frac{\alpha t^{\alpha - 1}}{\alpha(t-1)^{\alpha - 1}} = +\infty$$ so that $\phi$ is unbounded above on $(1,\infty)$.
Consider $t = \dfrac dc$ to see that the expression $$\frac{d^\alpha - c^\alpha}{(d-c)^\alpha}$$ has no upper bound for $0 < c < d$.
